# PHP gettext install failed on Mac OSX 10.8

Tags: php, macos, gettext

I'm having a problem getting gettext to work with PHP. My development Mac Book has Mac OSX 10.8 Mountain Lion as the OS. The installation instruction I follows is as below.

referencing to this post: [How to install gettext on MacOS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940383/how-to-install-gettext-on-macos-x)

```
#Install dependencies
brew install libjpeg
brew install pcre
brew install libxml2
brew install mcrypt

#Get autoconf just because
brew install autoconf

#Install Intl extension
#Install ICU
#Download from http://site.icu-project.org/download/48#ICU4C-Download
cd ~/Downloads
tar xzvf icu4c-4_8_1-src.tgz
cd icu/source
./runConfigureICU MacOSX
make
sudo make install

cd ~/Downloads/php-5.4.12/ext/intl
phpize
./configure --enable-intl
make
sudo cp modules/intl.so /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/

#Install gettext
#Download from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gettext/
cd ~/Downloads
tar xzvf gettext-0.18.1.1.tar.gz
cd gettext-0.18.1.1
./configure
make
sudo make install

cd ~/Downloads/php-5.4.12/ext/gettext
phpize
./configure 
make
sudo cp modules/gettext.so /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/

#Add intl and get text to php.ini
cd ~/Downloads/php-5.4.12
nano php.ini-development
#Add these lines
extension=intl.so
extension=gettext.so

#Download PHP source files from php.net
cd ~/Downloads
tar xzvf php-5.4.12.tar.bz2
cd php-5.4.12

./configure \
--prefix=/usr \
--with-gettext \
--mandir=/usr/share/man \
--infodir=/usr/share/info \
--sysconfdir=/private/etc \
--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs \
--enable-cli \
--with-config-file-path=/etc \
--with-libxml-dir=/usr \
--with-openssl=/usr \
--with-kerberos=/usr \
--with-zlib=/usr \
--enable-bcmath \
--with-bz2=/usr \
--enable-calendar \
--with-curl=/usr \
--enable-dba \
--enable-exif \
--enable-ftp \
--with-gd \
--enable-gd-native-ttf \
--with-icu-dir=/usr \
--with-iodbc=/usr \
--with-ldap=/usr \
--with-ldap-sasl=/usr \
--with-libedit=/usr \
--enable-mbstring \
--enable-mbregex \
--with-mysql=mysqlnd \
--with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
--without-pear \
--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
--with-mysql-sock=/var/mysql/mysql.sock \
--with-readline=/usr \
--enable-shmop \
--with-snmp=/usr \
--enable-soap \
--enable-sockets \
--enable-sysvmsg \
--enable-sysvsem \
--enable-sysvshm \
--with-tidy \
--enable-wddx \
--with-xmlrpc \
--with-iconv-dir=/usr \
--with-xsl=/usr \
--enable-zip \
--with-imap=/usr/local/imap-2007 \
--with-kerberos \
--with-imap-ssl \
--enable-intl \
--with-pcre-regex \
--with-pgsql=/usr \
--with-pdo-pgsql=/usr \
--with-freetype-dir=/usr/X11 \
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
--with-png-dir=/usr/X11

make test
sudo make install

#Restart Apache
sudo apachectl restart
```

every step seemed to work very well until "make test" command right after PHP .configure.

here is the error I got:

```
ibphp5.bundle libs/libphp5.so
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/gettext/gettext.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/php_intl.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/intl_error.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/intl_convert.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/collator/collator.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/collator/collator_class.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/collator/collator_sort.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/collator/collator_convert.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/collator/collator_locale.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/collator/collator_compare.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/collator/collator_attr.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/collator/collator_create.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/collator/collator_is_numeric.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/collator/collator_error.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/common/common_error.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/formatter/formatter.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/formatter/formatter_main.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/formatter/formatter_class.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/formatter/formatter_attr.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/formatter/formatter_data.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/formatter/formatter_format.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/formatter/formatter_parse.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/normalizer/normalizer.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/normalizer/normalizer_class.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/normalizer/normalizer_normalize.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/locale/locale.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/locale/locale_class.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/locale/locale_methods.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/dateformat/dateformat.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/dateformat/dateformat_class.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/dateformat/dateformat_attr.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/dateformat/dateformat_data.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/dateformat/dateformat_format.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/dateformat/dateformat_parse.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/msgformat/msgformat.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/msgformat/msgformat_attr.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/msgformat/msgformat_class.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/msgformat/msgformat_data.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/msgformat/msgformat_format.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/msgformat/msgformat_helpers.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/msgformat/msgformat_parse.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/grapheme/grapheme_string.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/grapheme/grapheme_util.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/resourcebundle/resourcebundle.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/resourcebundle/resourcebundle_class.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/resourcebundle/resourcebundle_iterator.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/transliterator/transliterator.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/transliterator/transliterator_class.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/transliterator/transliterator_methods.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/idn/idn.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/spoofchecker/spoofchecker_class.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/spoofchecker/spoofchecker.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/spoofchecker/spoofchecker_create.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/intl/spoofchecker/spoofchecker_main.o'
make: *** [libs/libphp5.bundle] Error 1
```

I was trying to google around for a solution, but unluckily nothing seemed to be found.
any one can help me with this to get it to work?

Comment: Are you running the script from the correct folder (ie, PHP’s unarchived source folder)?

Comment: @admdrew How can I determine which folder is unarchived source folder? Could you please explain more? Basically, I just downloaded the php source files from php website, then had it uncompressed, and worked in that folder using the above instructions. The reason is I'm trying to make an upgrade from php 5.3.13 which was originally built-in with Mac OSX.

Answer (score 0):

After the configure you need to compile php before you can run 'make test', so just run 'make':

```
make
make test
sudo make install
```