# envsubst: command not found on Mac OS X 10.8

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, sh, command-line-interface

When I try to run a script that contains the envsubst command, I get this error. Looking online, this seems to be a standard bash command, so I am not sure what to install in order to get it to work.

Comment: `envsubst` is included in `gettext` package. you may compile by your own. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940383/how-to-install-gettext-on-macos-x

Comment: I posted it as answer.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Edit: @cobberboy 's anwer is more correct. upvote him.

```
brew install gettext
brew link --force gettext
```

Following is my old answer:

`envsubst` is included in `gettext` package.

Therefore you may compile it by your own, using standard build tools such as `make` or using `homebrew`.

However, it seems to have little issue when installing `gettext` in MacOS.
See following url for details: [How to install gettext on MacOS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940383/how-to-install-gettext-on-macos-x)

Comment: While `envsubst` is part of gettext (as installed by homebrew) it is not linked by default. I expect this is because gettext is a keg-only formula. You could tell homebrew to link the keg, but this might have unintended side-effects. A less intrusive approach is to setup an alias by adding `alias envsubst='/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.19.6/bin/envsubst'` to your `.profile` (or equivalent). Of course, you may have another version of gettext installed. You can learn about it by running `brew info gettext`.

Comment: @trkoch You probably want to alias `/usr/local/opt/gettext/bin/envsubst` which survives upgrades

Comment: While this is the accepted answer, please scroll down to @cobberboy's answer, as it is also a common probably that you need to force the link.

Comment: I wondered why I was suddenly getting more upvotes. Thanks for your generosity @ymonad

Comment: Linking /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.19.8.1... 194 symlinks created ... wtf 194 symlinks?

Answer (score 284):

```
brew install gettext
brew link --force gettext
```

This will enable envsubst on OS X, and force it to link properly. It requires homebrew to be installed.

Comment: `Linking /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.19.8.1... 194 symlinks created` ... wtf 194 symlinks?

Comment: @AlexanderMills yeah `gettext` includes a hell of a lot of stuff; it seems like overkill just to get `envsubst` installed but it's the quickest and simplest way.

Comment: seems like they're symlinking every file instead of just symlinking a folder

Comment: @AlexanderMills Yes, this is how Homebrew works: it symlinks each executable into `/usr/bin`. There's not really a good way to symlink a single directory there and have each executable be available on the shell PATH.

Answer (score 23):

To clear up potential confusion:

- `envsubst` is an ***external* executable and thus *not part of Bash***; external executables are *platform-dependent*, both in terms of which ones are available as well as their specific behavior and the specific options they support (though, hopefully, there is a common subset based on the POSIX specifications)
- **Commands directly built into `bash` are called *builtins*, and only *they* can be relied upon to be present on *all* platforms**.

To **test whether a given command is a builtin**, use

```
type <cmdName>
```

In the case at hand, running `type envsubst` on macOS 10.13 returns `-bash: type: envsubst: not found`, from which you can infer:

- `envsubst` is NOT a builtin
- `envsubst` is not in your system's `$PATH` (and thus likely not present on your system)

(By contrast, running the same on command on, e.g., a Ubuntu 12.04 system returns `envsubst is hashed (/usr/bin/envsubst)`, which tells you that the utility is present and where it is located.)

---

A makeshift alternative to `envsubst` is to use `eval`, although the usual caveat applies: use `eval` only on strings whose content you control or trust:

Assume a `sample.txt` file containing text with unexpanded variable references; e.g.:

```
cat > sample.txt <<'EOF'
Honey, I'm $USER
and I'm $HOME.
EOF
```

The equivalent of:

```
envsubst < sample.txt
```

is:

```
eval "echo \"$(sed 's/"/\\"/g' sample.txt)\""
```

There is a **crucial difference**, however:

- **`envsubst`** expands ***only environment* variable references**
- whereas **`eval`** will expand ***shell* variable references *too*** - as well as **embedded *command substitutions***, which is what makes use of `eval` a **security concern.**

Comment: I like the idea of `eval echo` because I trust the source but it's not the same.. `envsubst < .env.example` can not just be `eval echo < .env.example`

Answer (score 4):

I'm using this now in my bash script that requires envsubst:

```
if ! which envsubst > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    envsubst() {
        while read line; do
            line=$( echo $line | sed 's/"/\\"/g' )
            eval echo $line
        done
    }
fi
```

you can use it as the envsubst command - of course it's not feature complete or something else:

```
envsubst <<<'Honey, I am $HOME.'
envsubst < input > output 2> corrupt
```

Comment: This seems to strip all leading and trailing whitespace

Comment: as said this is a workaround that is not feature complete. you could try adding `"` around $line but I did not try this yet

Comment: This approach seems to handle whitespace properly and is faster:

`sed 's/"/\\"/g' | eval "echo \"$(cat -)\""`

Comment: @EvanOwen nice. does that replace the whole while loop? it looks like it... I would like to update the answer then.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to bother installing homebrew and gettext, a one line perl executable will do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
$_ =~ s/\Q${$1||$2}/$ENV{$1?$2:$4}/ while $_ =~ /(\$\{([^}]+)})|(\$(\w+))/g;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to bother installing homebrew and gettext, and [can't make heads or tails of perl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61372385/83144), a simple python script also does the trick:

```bash
envsubst() {
  python -c 'import os,sys;[sys.stdout.write(os.path.expandvars(l)) for l in sys.stdin]'
}
```

The advantage of this over `eval` solutions is that it only handles variable replacement and won't execute arbitrary scripts like `eval` does.

```
$ cat > sample.txt <<'EOF'
Honey, I'm $USER
and I'm $HOME.
Danger: $( echo 'eval can do evil here, but python expandvars rocks' )
EOF

$ envsubst < sample.txt

Honey, I'm mattmc3
and I'm /Users/mattmc3.
Danger: $( echo 'eval can do evil here, but python expandvars rocks' )
```