# How Can You Perform Variable Substitution using Kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to create a `Role` and `RoleBinding` so I can use Helm. I want to use variable substitution somehow to replace `{{namespace}}` with something when I run an `apply` command.

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: tiller-manager-{{namespace}}
  namespace: {{namespace}}
rules:
- apiGroups: ["", "batch", "extensions", "apps"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
```

I want to pass the namespace something like this:

> kubectl apply --file role.yaml --namespace foo

I have seen that `kubectl apply` has a [--template](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands) parameter but I can't see much information about how it might be used.

Comment: For what you’ve shown here, you don’t need to specify the namespace in the YAML file: `kubectl` has a `--namespace` option to fill that item in, and since resource names are namespace-scoped, you can have the same role name in multiple namespaces safely.

Comment: But I'm using the namespace to also modify the name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in following way.

1. Write `Role` file like this:

   ```
   kind: Role
   apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
   metadata:
     name: tiller-manager-${NAMESPACE}
     namespace: ${NAMESPACE}
   rules:
   - apiGroups: ["", "batch", "extensions", "apps"]
     resources: ["*"]
     verbs: ["*"]
   ```
2. Set `NAMESPACE` environment variable to your desired value.
3. Then create Role using following command

   ```
   envsubst < role.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
   ```

Comment: I guess I have to install `envsubst` though first.

Comment: If you are using Mac check answer from this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620827/envsubst-command-not-found-on-mac-os-x-10-8

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can use. With `sed` command you can replace `{{namespace}}` directly. without setting any environment variable or using `envsubst`.

1. First save your role in a file say `role.yaml` which contains original content.
2. Then use `sed  's/{{namespace}}/your-namespace-name/g' role.yaml`. which print in `stdout` the desired file. Replaced `{{namespace}}` with `your-namespace-name`.

N.B: you can also save it in a file using `sed  's/{{namespace}}/your-namespace-name/g' role.yaml > new-role.yaml`

Answer (score 1):

Can be done like this.

```
cat .env
IMAGE_SOURCE=hello
IMAGE_VERSION=2.3.4
```

*source .env; kustomize build dev | envsubst*

Comment: source .env; kustomize build dev | envsubst | kubectl create -f -